# Tkinter how to size a spinbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to size a `ttk.Spinbox` to fill a frame but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.
In the sample code below I create three widgets an `Entry` and a `tk.Spinbox` and a `ttk.Spinbox`. The `Entry` widget sizes to fill the frame and so does `tk.Spinbox` but the `ttk.Spinbox` doesn't. How can I get the `ttk.Spinbox` to fill the frame? I need the `ttk.Spinbox` to do the same as the `tk.Spinbox`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

var1 = tk.StringVar()
var1.set('Test')
ent = ttk.Entry(frame, textvariable=var1)

var2 = tk.IntVar()
var2.set('1')
spn1 = tk.Spinbox(frame, textvariable=var2,  values=tuple(range(1, 101)))
spn2 = ttk.Spinbox(frame, textvariable=var2,  values=tuple(range(1, 101)))

ent.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
spn1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)
spn2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)

frame.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a tcl/tk issue, I have just tried in tcl and the `ttk::spinbox` does not fill the frame either. I found an old tcl/tk [ticket](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktview/3313032fffffffffffff) but no fix has been suggested yet.

Comment: Okay thank you, is there something I can do to get their attention on this ticket seems to me that this is a necessary thing that needs to work. How can one style a page when the widgets don't respond to commands.

Comment: I have looked at the source code of tk and I have realized that the issue comes from the theme layout for the `ttk.Spinbox`. I have tweaked the elements settings in various ways but I haven't manage to make the arrow buttons expand in a satisfying way. I guess this is why the `ttk.Spinbox` was made not to resize. If you want a nice `ttk.Spinbox`, I think you will have to make it yourself using `ttk.Entry` and `ttk.Button`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@j_4321: Nice job, now insert a line to configure the arrowsize:

```
style.configure('resize1.TSpinbox', arrowsize=25)
```

Comment: Wonderful, same works for a TCombobox too, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to make the text area expand by changing the `TSpinbox` layout using the style. Unfortunately I haven't manage to resize the buttons:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)

style.layout('resize1.TSpinbox', [('Spinbox.field',
  {'expand': 1,
   'sticky': 'nswe',
   'children': [('null',
     {'side': 'right',
      'sticky': 'ns',
      'children': [('Spinbox.uparrow', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': 'e'}),
       ('Spinbox.downarrow', {'side': 'bottom', 'sticky': 'e'})]}),
    ('Spinbox.padding',
     {'sticky': 'nswe',
      'children': [('Spinbox.textarea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})]})])

style.layout('resize2.TSpinbox', [('Spinbox.field',
  {'expand': 1,
   'sticky': 'nswe',
   'children': [('null',
     {'side': 'right',
      'sticky': 'e',
      'children': [('Spinbox.uparrow', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': 'e'}),
       ('Spinbox.downarrow', {'side': 'bottom',  'sticky': 'e'})]}),
    ('Spinbox.padding',
     {'sticky': 'nswe',
      'children': [('Spinbox.textarea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})]})])

ttk.Spinbox(root).pack(fill='both', expand=True)
ttk.Spinbox(root, style='resize1.TSpinbox').pack(fill='both', expand=True)
ttk.Spinbox(root, style='resize2.TSpinbox').pack(fill='both', expand=True)

root.geometry('400x400')
root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]